# Difference between Typed Style and setting ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a `Style` for my `TreeViewItems` which at the moment is applied to all because he has no `Key`.

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">            
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="gChildren">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorLin" Grid.Row="0" Height="1" Stroke="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerLinUp" Grid.Row="1" Width="1" Height="20" Stroke="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                        <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Padding="6" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0">
                            <ContentPresenter Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>                            
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerLinDown" Grid.Row="3" Width="1" Height="10" Stroke="Black" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemPresenter" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                            
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource IsGreaterThanConv}, ConverterParameter=0}" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="VerLinDown" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>                            
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource HasParentMoreChildren}}" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="HorLin" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>                            
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsParentTreeViewItem}}" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="VerLinUp" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>                            
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsParentTreeViewItem}}" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="VerLinUp" Property="Height" Value="10" />
                        </DataTrigger>                            
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsFirstOrLastItem}}" Value="2">
                            <Setter TargetName="HorLin" Property="Width" Value="{Binding ElementName=gChildren, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}, ConverterParameter=/2}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="HorLin" Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        </DataTrigger>                            
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsFirstOrLastItem}}" Value="1">
                            <Setter TargetName="HorLin" Property="Width" Value="{Binding ElementName=gChildren, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}, ConverterParameter=/2}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="HorLin" Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        </DataTrigger>                            
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemAreaBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="spChildren" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="4,0,4,6" Orientation="Horizontal" />                        
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>            
    </Style>
```

When I leave it like that everything works like I want it too. But if I give my `Style` a Name and set the `ItemContainerStyle` on my `TreeView` it looks different

```
<Style x:Key="GoodTVI" TargetType="TreeViewItem">            
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="gChildren">
```

Adding my `TreeViewItem`-Style to my `TreeView`

```
    TVVerlauf.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemContainerStyleProperty, "GoodTVI");
```

The Rest of the `Style` stays exactly the same. This is the only difference but the Result looks completley different.

Answer (score 0):

> I give my Style a Name

Actually, you don't.

```
<Style x:Key="GoodTVI" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    ...
```

That's not a name. That's a key. The `Style` is a resource. Resources have keys, not names. The two are different. For one thing, resource keys are objects rather than strings. And they're looked up differently, in different places.

Here, you're binding the treeview's `ItemContainerStyle` property to the `GoodTVI` property of its `DataContext` (which should be your viewmodel).

```
TVVerlauf.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemContainerStyleProperty, "GoodTVI");
```

Since `GoodTVI` is a resource key, not the name of a property on the viewmodel, you're naturally not getting good results.

Try this on your `TreeView` in the XAML:

```
<TreeView
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GoodTVI}"
    ...other properties...
    >
```

If you need to do this in C#, try this:

```
TVVerlauf.ItemContainerStyle = (DataTemplate)TVVerlauf.FindResource("GoodTVI");
```

Comment: My `TreeView` is completley generated in Code. How do I set this in Code?

Comment: @E-Nuff Oh, my God. Why would you do a thing like that? *Why?* Well, now you know not to do that in WPF. Updating my answer -- this is just shrewd a guess though, since I've never tortured myself that way. (UPDATE: Or been tortured that way by my predecessors!)

Comment: Well thats what happens when you are not the original developer of the project.

Comment: Still doesn't works but thanks for the Help anyway :)

Comment: @E-Nuff The resource may be out of scope, not "visible" from where the TreeView sits. If you can get to the resource dictionary instance where the Style is defined, you could look it up directly in the dictionary object. That's going to depend on the details of your project.

Comment: It works for the Root Children but not the following CHildren that seems weird.

Comment: @E-Nuff I think it may not be passing along the ItemContainerStyle to the children. I'm googling and not seeing anything helpful. Here's a Where you now assign the style, instead create a new Style instance, set its `TargetType` to `typeof(TreeViewItem)` and its `BasedOn` property to `GoodTVI` (which you can find now, right?), *don't give it a key* -- just add it to a new empty resource dictionary and assign that to `TVVerlauf.Resources` (or if `TVVerlauf.Resources` is not null, just add your new style to that). It'll be "locally global"
for that TreeView only.

Comment: I found a different way. I added the `TreeView` in XAML and then added the `Style` in the `TreeView.Resources`. Via Code I add the root `TreeViewItem`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
TVVerlauf.SetBinding(TreeView.StyleProperty, "GoodTVI");
```